# Maintain Session when logged in across all Pages, End session after set time (OWA_COOKIE)

Tags: sql, oracle, cookies, plsql

I need to maintain a session for session credentials throughout the web pages I have made. I have next to no experience using OWA_COOKIE and am unsure how to go about it.

I just need it to maintain the session, Finish session if

1. inactive for 15 mins OR 2. they log out

I have had a whirl at it and this what I have but it doesn't work and am at a lose, can someone help or point me in the right direction?

```
FUNCTION maintain_session_cookie  
   AS

   TYPE vc_arr IS TABLE OF varchar2(4000)
INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER.

TYPE cookie IS RECORD (
NAME varchar2(4000),
vals vc_arr,
num_vals integer);

  BEGIN
   owa_util.mime_header('', FALSE);
   owa_cookie.send(
      NAME=>'Session_Cookie',
      VALUE=>LOWER(),
      expires => SYSDATE + 365);

   -- Set the cookie and redirect to another page
   owa_util.redirect_url();
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;
END;
```

I have been just fiddling to see how it works and provide the functionality that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is a quite awkward way to set session lifetime by cookies. You can setup the parameter `timeout-secs` *in either web.xml or weblogic.xml* (see [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/sessions.htm)).

Your both requirements should be processed by the HTTP server, that's my point of view.

Now, let's say you still want to use cookies (maybe you do not use WebLogic or another reason, whatever). You will face following problems:

1. You will need to specify these cookies on **every** page you will display to the user, and not only pages, every ajax call should also have the cookies. So, everything which shows user activity should have this cookie.
2. Expires parameter should, obviously, be `sysdate + interval '15' minute`, then your cookie will work exactly for 15 minutes and if you do like it is written in point 1 the cookie will be lost only if there is no activity.
3. You will have to close the session by yourself if the cookie is not more presented in HTTP request, this is an additional problem.

The thing I want to say is: do it with server configuration and not with cookies. This will save your time and nerves.

Comment: Thanks very much, this helps a bit I will look into the server configuration side of things if its easier and better to use :) Thank you

Comment: @Studento919, no problem :) if you have any questions more concerning this topic, better ask on admin forums, this is a question for them mostly :) we are just programmers